# Andrjoid JNI simple for next return an error

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

```
    jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_buildString(JNIEnv *env, jobject sThis){
        for (int i=0; i < 100000; i++){
              char* c=(char*)env->NewStringUTF("xx");
        }

        return env->NewStringUTF("test");
    }
```

> 12-04 14:46:36.399: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8086): Trying to load lib
>   /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so 0x405143d8 12-04
>   14:46:36.399: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8086): Added shared lib
>   /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so 0x405143d8 12-04
>   14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086): ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)
>   12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086): Last 10 entries in JNI local
>   reference table: 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1014:
>   0x4052b258 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1015: 0x4052b298 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28
>   bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1016: 0x4052b2d8
>   cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1017: 0x4052b318 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28
>   bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1018: 0x4052b358
>   cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1019: 0x4052b398 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28
>   bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1020: 0x4052b3d8
>   cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1021: 0x4052b418 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28
>   bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1022: 0x4052b458
>   cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(8086):  1023: 0x4052b498 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28
>   bytes) 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086): JNI local reference
>   table summary (1024 entries): 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):
>   1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 236B 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):
>   1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 284B 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086):
>   1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 572B 12-04 14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086): 
>   1020 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (1020 unique) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(8086):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 28B 12-04
>   14:46:36.431: WARN/dalvikvm(8086): Memory held directly by tracked
>   refs is 29680 bytes 12-04 14:46:36.431: ERROR/dalvikvm(8086): Failed
>   adding to JNI local ref table (has 1024 entries) 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(8086): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE 12-04 14:46:36.431:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(8086):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0
>   obj=0x4001f1b8 self=0xcee8 12-04 14:46:36.431: INFO/dalvikvm(8086):
>   | sysTid=8086 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496 12-04
>   14:46:36.431: INFO/dalvikvm(8086):   at
>   com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.buildString(Native Method) 12-04
>   14:46:36.431: INFO/dalvikvm(8086):   at
>   com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.onCreate(HelloJni.java:93)

weird. if my for next looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++){
```

then evreything ok.

How can I rewrite this code to run the for next with a big number?

Comment: What's the purpose of that loop exactly?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your question. To much code and too less text. Please describe exactly what you want to achieve and what your problem is.

Comment: I d like to run a big running for next cycle in C, that called from JNI/Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are invoking this method from the UI thread then it will pause for 1.4 minutes and android will close any program that does not respond for 5 seconds my this help you try to use AsyncTask or execute this call in another thread .

Comment: ok, how can I rewrite it to not close android? async? or thread? or how? (c thread or java?)

Comment: if you want to access the UI thread after this function call use Handlers or AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You allocate too many Java objects in one JNI function call. Dalvik tells you that you've occupied the whole object reference table (1024 objects in your case). So, use Java arrays or another way to store your data.

Each time you call NewStringUTF it will copy your string into memory 'owned' by Java, and will assign an object to govern the Java version of the string (and the memory used on the Java side). When your reference goes out of the scope (in the above example, when the native functions returns) the memory Java has allocated will be made free and the reference will be dropped.

Each time a local reference is stored on the Java side (to track an object and its memory) it uses a slot in a table. I am not sure how big this table is guaranteed to be, but I'm pretty sure it's relatively small, maybe 32 entries. In your case it is actually 1024 big (implementation specific) but either way there is a limit, if you exceed it you will get the crash you are experiencing.

In terms of how to get around this problem, well the obvious rule is to use less local references. From your code snippet it isn't clear what the for loop is meant to be doing, but the cast to a (char*) suggests a fundamental lack of understanding of what the code is actually doing. If you kept it as a jstring, you have the option of subsequently calling env->DeleteLocalRef( ... ) to remove the reference. Anyway, please provide further information if there is something specific you are trying to achieve.